# Google Play Console: Your app doesn't have any in-app products yet

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm going to add IAP in my application, I followed the tutorial below, and I found that I need to create a product to have its ID to implement it in my app.

But when I went to Google Play Console it asks me to first upload an APK that has the Billing permission.

Which doesn't make sense to me and confuses me, Why?

Because I should be able to firstly create the product and have its ID, so I can put it in my app then upload the APK for publish.

Am I missing something here?

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I uploaded a version of my app that has the Billing permission to Alpha which solved my problem, I hope it may help others in the future.

Comment: I.e. stick this in your AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`